# Use Python to search online database and download images

Tags: python, database, python-3.x, image

I'd like my Python code to iterate through a numpy array and search an online database with each of these numbers. This seems fairly complicated, since it must enter the number into a certain search box after navigating to the URL, and then I would like it to return all the images that appear after searching for each number (there are multiple images in each search result). Is there a straightforward way to do this?

Comment: Does whatever website you're interacting with expose endpoints for your code to call?  Look at the URL of the page you end up at after a search: could you navigate to that URL directly with the information you have?  If not, you'll likely have to use a browser automation framework like selenium.

Comment: The URL after a search contains a couple unique pieces of information, but I will only know one thing (the number), which is all that's required to search. But it looks like I won't be able to just edit the URL since I won't know the other information.

Comment: If this helps, the URL for the search part of the database is: http://irsa.ipac.caltech.edu/applications/wise/#id=Hydra_wise_wise_5&RequestClass=ServerRequest&projectId=wise&shortDesc=Solar%20System%20Object/Orbit&isBookmarkAble=true&isDrillDownRoot=true

Comment: Can you use an html-parsing package to scrape the pictures (such as beautiful soup: https://launchpad.net/beautifulsoup), or do you have to hit the DB directly?